# Sample multiple vectors from the same values with predefined mean correlation

Tags: r

I'm drawing multiple samples from the same vector. My intended goal is to generate distributions of the maxima of row sums as different parameters vary.

```
# set seed
set.seed(24601) 

# generate vector of values
values <- c(1:10)

# create five different configurations of these values
configuration <- 
  replicate(5,
           sample(values, 10))

# what's the maximum rowsum?
max(rowSums(configuration))
```

However, I'd like to do this in a way that allows me to define the correlations between the columns. Basically, I'd like this:

```
mean(cor(configuration)[lower.tri(cor(configuration))])
```

to be something I can define when starting the process.

The guidance that I can find on related issues is very helpful for generating random variables, but I'm struggling to find something for random samples. Basically I'm looking for a **sample()** equivalent to **rnorm_multi**.

Thanks in advance!

Edit to add: [Pieter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10781678/pieter-bulls) has raised the possibility of creating a large number of samples, and then only retaining a set of samples that conforms to the requirements. In the event that I ran something as follows:

```
configuration_large <- 
  replicate(1000,
          sample(values, 10))
```

in order to retain a smaller number of columns with a mean correlation within a given range (say, between 0.3 and 0.4). He's provided a helpful guide on how to do that, but it's not realistic for larger samples (for example, if we take samples 50 times rather than 5 times and want a correlation of at least 0.3).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this exists without knowing or assuming more about the `values` you are sampling, short of generating too many samples and only retaining those with the desired statistics.

If you can define a distribution on `values` you can use copulas to generate random correlated data. I only have a described example in [SAS](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/07/05/introduction-copulas.html) at hand, but the idea is that you'd simulate standard multivariate normal data with known correlation, turn those into quantiles, and then invert the quantiles into your target distribution. A small hitch is that such transformations will not exactly maintain Pearson (or other parametric) correlations.

Comment: Thanks. The <code>values</code> in question is a vector of specific integers. The solution of only retaining those with the desired statistics would also work as a solution - do you have a suggestion for how to do this?

Comment: Sure, here's a very simple example that selects for mean cor > 0.2:
```
set.seed(24601) 
values <- c(1:10)
samples <- list()
i <- 0

while(i < 10) {
  configuration <- replicate(5, sample(values, 10))
  sample_cor <- mean(cor(configuration)[lower.tri(cor(configuration))])
  
  if (sample_cor > 0.2) {
    i <- i + 1
    samples[[i]] <- configuration
  }
}

# Confirm that all are >.20
vapply(samples, function(s) mean(cor(s)[lower.tri(cor(s))]), numeric(1))
[1] 0.2448485 0.2072727 0.2048485 0.2157576 0.2145455 0.2557576 0.2496970 0.3769697 0.2630303 0.2230303
```

Comment: Oh dear, that really messed up formatting & I don't have enough characters to do it the proper way (4 space indent in each line)... Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/rBEsR4nD